# Can you put Code Contracts on Private Fields?

Tags: c#, field, code-contracts

For the sake of simplicity, say I have a private field that caches my collection's count:

```
private int _count;
```

I would like to ensure that the count is never below zero. I can check this in the invariant:

```
[ContractInvariantMethod]
private void invariant(){
    Contract.Invariant(_count >= 0);
}
```

However, this is only going to catch the mistake when exiting a public method – not when it happens. The value could be assign by a more complicate algorithm, so getting the exact time where it fails can be valuable.

I could wrap the contract in a property like this:

```
public int Count {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
        return _count;
    }
    private set {
        Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
        _count = value;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't really ensure that I don't access the field directly, and it add the extra overhead of going through a property when altering the value internally. Since the setter is private I can't stick the contract on an interface either.

Is it possible to maybe annotate the field with a contract to ensure it is check when setting it?

Comment: "Overhead" when altering the value internally? You care so much about tiny performance differences and you never checked if the property access is inlined? :P Check the disassembly - simple properties like this are almost always inlined.

Comment: I have experienced big differences in using properties instead of using fields directly. This might not exactly be the case with a cached count value, but a value that is written more often can definitely show negative effects when hidden behind a property. I kept the example simple for to be able to focus on the actual question of contracts – my real problem doesn't concern a count variable. And it still doesn't change the fact that you can access the value directly, thereby avoiding the contract!

Comment: Big differences in *release* build, without the debugger attached? I doubt that. If the debugger is attached the inlining is prevented, of course. Even then, the overhead is tiny, so it only really gives you trouble in high-throughput scenarios - and in that case, you're simply going to optimize for high performance even at the cost to maintenance (i.e. "everyone writing to this field must use the correct preconditions"). You can't eat your cake and have it too - the contracts must be *somewhere*. Are you using the contracts for static analysis only?

Comment: As for hiding the field, there really are only two options - either hide it in a parent class (making the property setter `protected`), or hide it in a `struct` that only exposes those properties and keeps the fields private.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a property is the best approach both in terms of performance and stability.

```
public int Count {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 0);
        return _count;
    }
    private set {
        Contract.Requires(value >= 0);
        _count = value;
    }
}
```

> But this doesn't really ensure that I don't access the field directly...

True, but you as the code author can make sure the field is never accessed directly. If that's too risky (large team, undisciplined programmers, etc.), you could move the `Count` property to a base class that has a simpler implementation.

> ...it add the extra overhead of going through a property when altering the value internally.

True, and you'll have to decide between performance and ensuring stability. If you really need to shave off every possible millisecond from your performance time, consider a different approach for getting and setting this Count value, such as replacing the public property with public GetCount() and/or SetCount() methods (not sure if methods incur the same overhead has properties, I'm just throwing some ideas around).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [possible using PostSharp's attribute `Required`](http://doc.postsharp.net/adding-contracts#adding-contracts-from-UI):

```
[Required]
private int _count;
```

They give the following example:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    [Required]
    private string mFirstName = “Not filled in yet”;

    public void SetFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        mFirstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

And say

> In this example, firstName will be validated by the Required contract before being assigned to mFirstName. Placing a contract on a field provides the added benefit of validating the field regardless of where it’s set from.

It is worth noting, that though this works, it doesn't take advantage of Microsoft's Code Contracts.